# How to mute the call audio and mute the user in teams tab app

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm developing the Teams Tab App and I want to create separate buttons in the Tab App to mute the call audio and user audio.

Is there any other way, than using [call: mute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [participant: mute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API endpoints? Unfortunately, these endpoints require a call-id, which can be obtained only in the response after creating a call or through the bot. I'm using Microsft Teams JavaScript Client SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do this per se, but just on the off-chance maybe this will be helpful, or as an alternative: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/muting-and-unmuting-your-mic-in-teams-17886394-9a9a-4f04-b4cc-e46589408b28#:~:text=Use%20Ctrl%2BSpacebar%20to%20unmute,back%20to%20muted%20state%20again](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/muting-and-unmuting-your-mic-in-teams-17886394-9a9a-4f04-b4cc-e46589408b28#:%7E:text=Use%20Ctrl%2BSpacebar%20to%20unmute,back%20to%20muted%20state%20again).

Answer (score 0):

Teams don't provide any call API to remote control the call in any way.

The only way to control a call is when you are controlling the call itself (meaning you are a call bot).

The API you point to are when you are a call bot and you are muting yourself (the call bot) in a call.  They don't control any other call leg or any other live call they are not in.

All you are left with, if you really need to control calls, is to do not nice things.  Like controlling the teams client from out side of the teams client. e.g. sending in the key presses or mouse clicking events into the OS or using Accessibility apis to remote control the teams app so that you hope the teams client do what you want it to do.  Not really recommnended as they not work 100% of the time but will work if you really need it to work.